# Understanding the code structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

What means and what will do this piece of code?

```
(function ($) {}(jQuery));
```

1. What is relation between "$" and "jQuery".
2. Do brackets "(", ")" on edges of code has any function? Do they do something?

Comment: @Teemu not exacly the same structure

Comment: There's no difference between `(f{}())` and `(f{})()` structures. Please read the answers at the linked post.

Comment: Thank you for this informations.

Comment: Googling `what is (function ($) {}(jQuery));` brought me right to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function ($) {}(jQuery));
```

`jQuery` is existing `jQuery` object , `$` is same `jQuery` object within [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) statement `{}`

> Do brackets "(", ")" on edges of code has any function? Do they do
>   something?

Yes. Comma `,` separates arguments to function

e.g.,

```js
(function($, $$) {
  // `$`:`{"abc":123}` ; `$$`:`{"def":456}`
  console.log($["abc"], $$["def"]) // `123` , `456`
 // set `$` within IIFE to object `{"abc":123}` ,
 // set `$$` to object `{"def":456}`
}({"abc":123}, {"def":456}));
```

Answer (score 1):

What is relation between "$" and "jQuery"?

$ is shorthand for jQuery. Sometimes $ is disabled as it may conflict with other Javascript libraries you are using. It is otherwise identical.

and refer this

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/